# How to register payment for an invoice in Odoo using web APIs

Tags: python, odoo, xml-rpc

I'm trying to register a payment for an invoice that I created earlier via the API.

I posted the invoice as follows

```
models = xmlrpc.client.ServerProxy('{}/xmlrpc/2/object'.format(url))

models.execute_kw(db, uid, password, 'account.move', 'post', [[invoice_id]])
```

I want to register this payment and mark it as paid after it being posted. I'm trying to use a workflow similar to the one above like this

```
models.execute_kw(db, uid, password, 'account.payment', 'action_register_payment', [{"active_id":invoice_id}])
```

I've tried sending the required fields in the module as well . I don't get any errors but the invoice is still not being registered.

Anyone can help with this ? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [action_register_payment](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/13.0/addons/account/models/account_payment.py#L405) method will check if `active_ids` is in context and if not it will return an empty string.
To pass the context you need to pass a dict just after the args list like they passed the `fields` argument to the [read](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/13.0/webservices/odoo.html#read-records) method in the official XML-RPC documentation:

```
models.execute_kw(db, uid, password, 'account.payment', 'action_register_payment', [[]], {'context': {"active_ids": [invoice_id]}}
```

The method returns an action as a dictionary which will lead to a:

```
TypeError: cannot marshal <class \'odoo.tools.misc.frozendict\'>
```

You can use the [payment register](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/13.0/addons/account/models/account_payment.py#L733) wizard to create the invoice payments, you have to create a new payment register record then call the [create_payments](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/13.0/addons/account/models/account_payment.py#L844) method.

**Example:**

```
payment_register_id = models.execute_kw(db, uid, password, 'account.payment.register', 'create', [{'journal_id': bank_journal_id, 'payment_method_id': payment_method_id, 'invoice_ids': [(4, invoice_id)]}])
models.execute_kw(db, uid, password, 'account.payment.register', 'create_payments', [[payment_register_id]])
```

Comment: In this way of creating a payment, how can we pass the payment token and see the payment transaction getting created?