# How to register payment for invoice from python in Odoo v15 CE

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-15

I am trying to make a single action on a sales order in Odoo v15 CE that creates an invoice for the sales order and immediately posts it and registers a payment for it. The way I'm doing so is through a wizard method that looks like this:

```
def create_invoices(self):
    sale_orders = self.env['sale.order'].browse(self._context.get('active_ids', []))
    for order in sale_orders:
        order._create_invoices()
        for inv in order.invoice_ids:
            # make invoice:
            inv.action_post()
            # register payment
            # ????
```

Currently, it creates the invoice and posts it. I would like to add something like `inv.register_payment()` to the final line in order to register the payment.

I've fount the `action_register_payment` method of the `account.move` model and also looked into using the `account.payment.register` wizard but neither worked. I've also found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64501622/how-to-register-payment-for-an-invoice-in-odoo-using-web-apis) question, which is trying to do something similar, but through an XML-RPC call (from what I can tell).

Can anyone please explain how to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to post the invoices using `action_post` then register payment by creating a payment like in

https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/15.0/addons/account/wizard/account_payment_register.py#L496

`account.payment.register` is a wizard, that's why you need to create values for it, otherwise you can `action_register_payment` which is a window action that will trigger the wizard and then it's for the user to register the payment (which is the standard behavior of Odoo)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I tried doing it this way (with `payment_vals = {...}` and `create(payment_vals)` ) and I'm getting a user error that says "Journal Entry Draft Entry (* 72) (INV/2022/00001) is not valid. In order to proceed, the journal items must include one and only one outstanding payments/receipts account."

Do you know what could help?

Comment: The issue comes from the fact that you may have account move lines (aka journal items) with different outstanding payments/receipts accounts, because it's required to have only one. You cannot have more than 1 record in lequidity_lines Check https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/15.0/addons/account/models/account_payment.py#L761

Comment: Thanks! I tried to understand what exactly this error means or how to fix it, but I couldn't. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I ended up using the method by Kenly, as the default values worked for me. However, I marked this one as accepted as it is closer to the "official" way of doing it. Some official documentation or method on the account.move model would have been really helpful on Odoo's part.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, we'll consider adding this use case to our documentation

Answer (score 2):

You can create an `account.payment.register` record and pass the model and invoice ids in context then call `action_create_payments` to create the payment with the default values.

***Example:***

```
payment_register.with_context(
    {'active_model': 'account.move',
     'active_ids': inv.ids}
).create({}).action_create_payments()
```